# How to save the correct rotated image using camerax Front Camera?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I am using CameraX for developing my android application in which when I take the pricture in landscape mode or portrait mode the image captured and saved is mirror image.

I know that FRONT camera works in the same way. But what to do if I want to save the picture in the same way it was taken?

Here is the `buildUseCase()` Code I am using:

```
private fun buildUseCases() {

        val screenAspectRatio = Rational(width, height)
        val screenTargetRotation = display.rotation

        //Preview
        val previewConfig = PreviewConfig.Builder().apply {
            setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            setTargetRotation(screenTargetRotation)
            setLensFacing(lensFacing)
        }.build()

        preview = AutoFitPreviewBuilder.build(previewConfig, this)
        //End - Preview


        // Set up the capture use case to allow users to take photos
        val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
            setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
            setTargetRotation(screenTargetRotation)
            setLensFacing(lensFacing)
            setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MAX_QUALITY)
        }.build()


        imageCapture = ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig)
    }
```

Please help me with what to change to get correct image captured.

**Note: The camera facing is FRONT and it is in Landscape mode.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to read EXIF data of the image created & have to write your own custom controllers as per requirements & needs. It's very normal in most Android & iOS devices that the captured images get rotated & it must be handled accordingly. In most of the devices, the default orientation of the camera is set to landscape mode, so even if you take a pic in portrait mode it gets rotated to 90degrees.

From EXIF data, you can get the degree of the image rotated or if its mirrored & then you can handle it in the backend.

To rotate your image you can try

```
private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException 
{
    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImage.getPath());
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            return rotateImage(img, 90);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            return rotateImage(img, 180);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            return rotateImage(img, 270);
        default:
            return img;
    }
 }

private static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap img, int degree)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    img.recycle();
    return rotatedImg;
}
```

For the image flipping issue you can try this

```
public static Bitmap flip(Bitmap src, int type) 
{
     // create new matrix for transformation
     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
     matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);

     // return transformed image
     return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
 }
```

And then set the image to ImageView as

```
imgPreview.setImageBitmap(flip(bitmap));
```

Comment: Hi! Is there a way to use this answer by not saving image. In other words: Use ExifInterface and setting path to it from ImageProxy? If I understand from this answer, you save image and then use Exif to get info about rotation right? What If I just want to take photo without saving and still having issue with rotation. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful when using `img.recycle();`

It caused me a very weird and hard to track error because I was using the src Bitmap further in my project.
The error I got was:

`2021-04-28 10:47:30.073 13573-15598/APPNAME A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x70 in tid 15598 (pool-7-thread-1), pid 13573 (ev.APPNAME )
`

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the mirror effect of photos when taking a photo with the front camera, it is necessary to pass the metadata to the

ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions

Depending on which camera is in use, here is an example of what I do

```
        val metadata = ImageCapture.Metadata()
        metadata.isReversedHorizontal = cameraSelector == CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA

        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile)
            .setMetadata(metadata)
            .build()

       imageCapture.takePicture(outputOptions, executor, object: ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {})
```

Answer (score 1):

Received advice from someone on the CameraX team about the same issue in my own code.

> The thing missing from your code is reading the EXIF rotation from the
> saved Jpeg so you can set the rotation properly on the `ImageView`. You
> can do this with `ExifInterface`, or alternatively, just use a library
> that handles this for you, like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). The official sample,
> CameraXBasic, [uses the Glide approach](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/PhotoFragment.kt).

First, their proposal means you don't need to define `setTargetRotation(screenTargetRotation)` for `Preview` or `ImageCapture` to yield an image that displays with the correct rotation.

In case the official sample changes, here is how it used Glide:

```
Glide.with().load().into()
```

`load()` receives a reference to the captured image. If you saved it to a `File`, provide a reference to that `File`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but might come in very handy if you need to read EXIF information out of a byte[] instead of a already decompressed bitmap.

```
 /**
 * Returns the degrees, counted clockwise, from a byte[] instead of a already saved file.<br>
 *
 * @param jpeg the JPEG image byte[]
 * @return Exif orientation as either <b>0</b>, <b>90</b>, <b>180</b> or <b>270</b>
 */
public static int getExifOrientation(byte[] jpeg) {
    if (jpeg == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int offset = 0;
    int length = 0;

    // ISO/IEC 10918-1:1993(E)
    while (offset + 3 < jpeg.length && (jpeg[offset++] & 0xFF) == 0xFF) {
        int marker = jpeg[offset] & 0xFF;

        // Check if the marker is a padding.
        if (marker == 0xFF) {
            continue;
        }
        offset++;

        // Check if the marker is SOI or TEM.
        if (marker == 0xD8 || marker == 0x01) {
            continue;
        }
        // Check if the marker is EOI or SOS.
        if (marker == 0xD9 || marker == 0xDA) {
            break;
        }

        // Get the length and check if it is reasonable.
        length = pack(jpeg, offset, 2, false);
        if (length < 2 || offset + length > jpeg.length) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid JPEG length");
            return 0;
        }

        // Break if the marker is EXIF in APP1.
        if (marker == 0xE1 && length >= 8 &&
                pack(jpeg, offset + 2, 4, false) == 0x45786966 &&
                pack(jpeg, offset + 6, 2, false) == 0) {
            offset += 8;
            length -= 8;
            break;
        }

        // Skip other markers.
        offset += length;
        length = 0;
    }

    // JEITA CP-3451 Exif Version 2.2
    if (length > 8) {
        // Identify the byte order.
        int tag = pack(jpeg, offset, 4, false);
        if (tag != 0x49492A00 && tag != 0x4D4D002A) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid JPEG EXIF byte order");
            return 0;
        }
        boolean littleEndian = (tag == 0x49492A00);

        // Get the offset and check if it is reasonable.
        int count = pack(jpeg, offset + 4, 4, littleEndian) + 2;
        if (count < 10 || count > length) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid JPEG EXIF offset");
            return 0;
        }
        offset += count;
        length -= count;

        // Get the count and go through all the elements.
        count = pack(jpeg, offset - 2, 2, littleEndian);
        while (count-- > 0 && length >= 12) {
            // Get the tag and check if it is orientation.
            tag = pack(jpeg, offset, 2, littleEndian);
            if (tag == 0x0112) {
                // We do not really care about type and count, do we?
                int orientation = pack(jpeg, offset + 8, 2, littleEndian);
                switch (orientation) {
                    case 1:
                        return 0;
                    case 3:
                        return 180;
                    case 6:
                        return 90;
                    case 8:
                        return 270;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Unsupported EXIF orientation");
                return 0;
            }
            offset += 12;
            length -= 12;
        }
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "EXIF Orientation not found");
    return 0;
}

private static int pack(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length,
                        boolean littleEndian) {
    int step = 1;
    if (littleEndian) {
        offset += length - 1;
        step = -1;
    }

    int value = 0;
    while (length-- > 0) {
        value = (value << 8) | (bytes[offset] & 0xFF);
        offset += step;
    }
    return value;
}
```